Specific variables and simulating correlated data by using copulas
I want to simulate correlated data by using copulas, and I found this page, where they:

Simulate correlated multivariate normal data from a correlation matrix. The marginal distributions are all standard normal.
Use the standard normal CDF to transform the normal marginals to the uniform distribution.
Use inverse CDFs to transform the uniform marginals to whatever distributions you want.

And they show an example in SAS which I have done in R, like this:
library(MASS)
library(VGAM)  

set.seed(12345)
N <- 1000
# Define Sigma matrix
Sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), nrow = 2)
# 1. Generate correlated multivariate normal data Z
Z <- mvrnorm(n = N, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = Sigma)
# 2. Transform marginal variables to U(0,1)
U <- pnorm(Z)
# 3. Construct the marginals
gamma <- qgamma(U[, 1], shape = 4)
LN <- qlnorm(U[, 2], meanlog = 0.5, sdlog = 0.8)
X <- cbind(gamma, LN)

# Calculate rank correlations
rankCorrZ <- cor(Z, method = "spearman")[2]
rankCorrU <- cor(U, method = "spearman")[2]
rankCorrX <- cor(X, method = "spearman")[2]

# Calculate Pearson correlations
rhoZ <- cor(Z, method = "pearson")[2]
rhoX <- cor(X, method = "pearson")[2]

Print rank correlations and Pearson correlations
> print(rankCorrZ)
#[1] 0.471292
> print(rankCorrU)
#[1] 0.471292
> print(rankCorrX)
#[1] 0.471292
> print(rhoZ)
#[1] 0.4930677
> print(rhoX)
#[1] 0.4636544

I want to achieve same result but using customized distributions. That is I want to generate x and y which follows these specific distributions, as below
sigma_x <- 2
sigma_y <- 2
beta = c(4,1)
x <- rnorm(N, 0, sigma_x)
y <- beta[1] + beta[2]*x + sigma_y * rexp(N, rate = 1) - 1

And I tried to do the same procedure as above (the SAS example). However, I don't get similar correlation value compared to Z and U, which you can see below in testing. Why? Can someone please explain. What am I doing wrong?
Sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), nrow = 2)
Z <- rmvnorm(n = N, mean = c(0, 0), sigma = Sigma)
U <- pnorm(Z)
x <- qnorm(U[,1], mean = 0, sd = sigma_x)
y <- beta[1] + beta[2] * x + sigma_y * (qexp(U[,2], rate = 1) - 1)
# Transform uniform marginals to normal distribution with desired standard deviation
DATA <- cbind(x, y)

rankCorrZ <- cor(Z, method = "spearman")[2]
rankCorrU <- cor(U, method = "spearman")[2]
rankCorrDATA <- cor(DATA, method = "spearman")[2]
rhoZ <- cor(Z, method = "pearson")[2]
rhoDATA <- cor(DATA, method = "pearson")[2]

Testing
> print(rankCorrZ)
#[1] 0.4609489
> print(rankCorrU)
#[1] 0.4609489
> print(rankCorrDATA)
#[1] 0.8821912
> print(rhoZ)
#[1] 0.4830919
> print(rhoDATA)
#[1] 0.8609049


The use of beta[2] makes the two variables dependent and correlated even without the copula.

@jblood94 I'm glad that you answered, you answered in my previous post as well but I didn't have enough reputation points to comment on that post. However, I understand that beta[2] inherently introduces dependency and correlation between the two variables. But I'm still keen on exploring the copula approach as it offers flexibility and control over the correlation structure, which is my task for my analysis. Could you please provide any additional insights or suggestions on how I might proceed with incorporating the copula method effectively in this context?

Are you interested in maintaining the conditional distribution of y (P(y|x))? My previous answer shows how to get samples that preserve the marginal distributions of x and y, but the process does not maintain the conditional distribution of y.

In my case, I want x to be correlated with y, and y is a function of x. However, I'm still unsure about the theoretical underpinnings of the fcor function. Could you please provide a more detailed explanation of its theoretical basis? Additionally, I'd appreciate guidance on how to utilize the copula method in this case.

fcor creates the copula by arranging any random bivariate sample so that the two variables are in the same order as a bivariate normal (i.e., their spearman correlation coefficients are identical). This allows us to skip creating U and performing the inverse transform sampling. The results are equivalent for typical copulas, but the process using simple reordering (with sort and rank) tends to be faster.

I don't think I can provide any more help without a better understanding of the problem. I suggest editing your Cross Validated question to include the following: 1) Problem background (what is the motivation??), 2) How you arrived at the sampling scheme for x and y, and 3) How are the values of sigma, beta, and rho determined, and what range of values could they take?
